# Relationship Between 4 Variables

Tags: functions, relations

Let (a-1) d = b (c-1) such that $ a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R} $.

How do you find the relationships between a,b,c,d? Do you look at what makes both sides equivalent?

I considered 3 cases where:

- a = 1, b = 0 and $c,d \in \mathbb{R} $
- $ (a-1) \neq 0 $, $ b \neq 0 $, c = 1, and  $d \in \mathbb{R} $
- $ (a-1) \neq 0 $,  $\mspace{4mu}b,\mspace{4mu}c  \in \mathbb{R} $ and $ d =b(c-1)/(a-1) $

Should I be considering other cases such as isolating b in the same way as isolating d or would that be redundant?

Answer (score 0):

i would write: first case: $$d=0$$ then we have $$0=b(c-1)$$ and we get $$b=0$$ or $$c=1$$. Now we consider the case $$d\neq 0$$ and we can write $$a=\frac{b}{d}(c-1)+1$$

Comment: But does this cover all cases?  We canhave b=0 or c=1, b=0 and c=1, $ d \neq 0 $ and a isolated. What about the other cases I have shown in the original question?